# eventLimitClick goes to current month

Tags: angularjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-3

I am using FullCalendar, if a user clicks a + more, I wanted it to expand all events in the calendar so... I used eventLimitClick method like below. But if I click +more in the last month (April), it goes into May (current month), and if I go back to April, I can see those expanded events in calendar.

```
var eventLimitClick = function (info) {
            var eventExpandable = _.get(scope.options, 'expandEvents');
            if (eventExpandable && config.views.month.eventLimit < info.segs.length) {
                scope.expanded = true;
                calendar.fullCalendar('destroy');
                onload(info.segs.length);
            }
        };


var onload = function (limit) {
            $q.all({
                events: controller.getAllEvents(),
                resourceList: controller.getResourceList()
            }).then(function (data) {
                config.views.month.eventLimit = limit;
                config.events = data.events;
                config.resources = _.sortBy(data.resourceList, 'title');
                calendar.fullCalendar(config);
                calendarService.config.set(config);
            });
        };
```

Of course, I do not want it go to current month, is there any way to make it stay in April with expanded events? I searched relevant information but I can't find it, does anyone have some information about it?

Comment: it's not entirely clear how the code above would cause that. In particular the interaction between fullCalendar and Angular makes it a lot more complex. Can we have a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please? It would be great to be able to reproduce the error and see this in action...then we can try and debug it.

Comment: I think this is because I destroy current calendar and reload new calendar (so load current month), is there any way to expand events without destroying current calendar, when I implemented that codes, there is no way to expand events without destroying... so..

Comment: Again a full example which allows us to run your code and see the problem would really help us to understand what is happening. I personally can't imagine why you would need to entirely destroy the calendar, but I don't know enough about your setup to understand it fully. Have you tried using any of the rendering methods instead? (e.g. to render the calendar, or just re-render the events)

Comment: yes, as far as I remember, I tried, but I will try more carefully. at that time, i was able to achieve it only by using destroy. I add my onload method here.

Comment: Thanks but that still isn't a runnable demo of your issue